# как сохранить изменения js после перезагрузки сайта

Tags: javascript

у меня есть код
где btn-кнопка, при нажатии на которую elem становится disabled

```
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    elem.disabled = true;
})
```

мне нужно чтобы при перезагрузке страницы elem.disabled = true сохранялось и elem был disabled

как сделать?

Comment: Сохраняете нужное вам значение в [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), а при загрузке страницы проверяете наличие этого параметра в localStorage

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Answer (score 0):

Предложу такой вариант...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<style>
 
</style>
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', _ => {
  const elem = document.querySelector('#test')
  if (localStorage.getItem('elem')) elem.disabled = true;
  const btn = document.querySelector('#btn')
  btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    elem.disabled = true;
    localStorage.setItem('elem', 1)
  })
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id='test'>Test</button>
<button id='btn'>Выкл</button>
</body>
</html>
```